# Natural Join of two dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, natural-join

I'm trying to implement the same idea of Natural Join in Database but on Two dimensional Arrays, so What I'm trying to do is if I have

`A={[a,b],[a',b']} and B={[b,c], [b',c],[b,c']}`

The result of NaturalJoin(A,B) should be:

```
Result = {[a,b,c], [a,b,c'],[a',b',c]}
```

So after I find the shared column B and compare it in both arrays, how can I combine the rows? Can you please give me some hints on how to create the joinedTableau as I don't know the number of rows from the beginning of the join, how can I create it dynamically?

This is my pseudo code:

```
int[][] array1;
int[][] array2;
int shared = prtiallyEqualColumn(array1,array2);
           for(int i = 0; i <array1.length; i++)
                        {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j < array2.length; j++)
                            {
                                if(array1[i][shared] == array2[j][shared]) 
                                {
                                        for(int s = 0 ; s < shared; s++)
                                        {
                                            joinedTableau[joinedCountRow][s] = array1[i][s];
                                        }
                                        for(int y=shared+1; y<array2.length;y++)
                                        {
                                            joinedTableau[joinedCountRow][y] = array2[j][y];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Being a seasoned user on SO, I believe you already know that you need to show us some pseudo code indicating what you have tried so far? (for the record, I did not downvote you yet but others might not be so generous)

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. This should increase your chances of getting an answer. (+1 from me)

Comment: Couldn't you compare all second elements from first array with all first elements from second array and if they match, insert them to result list?

Comment: Shouldn't the result be - Result = {[a,b,c], [a,b,c'],[a',b',c], [a,b,b',c],[a',b',c']}

Comment: No I'm not doing a Cartesian Product, the algorithm will only join two rows if there is a shared column.

Comment: So does column2 of the array1 needs to be mapped with column1 or array2 or can it also be mapped to column2 or array2?

Comment: Yea it can be mapped to any equal column, depends on array1 and array2 content, that's why I'm calling prtiallyEqualColumn it gives me the shared column index in array2.

Comment: I mean by "equal" they are all B either b or b'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you've done in the code as you have hidden several implementations from the code presented here in the question. I am giving you the algo :-

> Each column value of array1 must be compared with each row value of
>   array2 to produce a natural join,only in case if they are equal, else
>   not.

```
a1 = array1.countRow();
a2 = array1.countColumn();
b1 = array2.countRow();
b2 = array2.countColumn();
i = j = 1;
while(i<=a1)
while(j<=b1)
if(array1[i][a2]==array2[j][1]) // I've made array-indices start from 1
// perform natural-join operation between array1[i]+array2[j]-common_element
// Similarly iterate the array for next passes.
```

If there is some mistake or something which is unclear to you,please notify me. Good luck for your code.

Comment: Can you post how can I assign the rows to the result array?

Comment: @Lisa-That's a kind of homework to you. But,still I'll give hint. Add array1[i]+array2[j]-common element which you have compared for equality using a for loop to the ArrayList! Can't think for a better solution now. Will update as soon as I think something effective.

Answer (score 0):

This yields the right answer.
is it the most efficient? I posted the results of my timing. definitely exponential growth in times

| count | avg time |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1.931190E-05 |
| 100 | 4.734993E-04 |
| 1000 | 2.540604E-02 |
| 10000 | 1.400114E+00 |
| 100000 | 9.096992E+01 |

```
#!python3
from time import time


def natural_join( S, T):
    theJoin = []
    for i in T:
        for j in S:
            if i[0] == j[1]:
                theJoin.append((i[1], j[0], j[1]))
                break
        
    return theJoin


for n in range(1, 6):
    A = []
    B = []
    for i in range(10 ** n):
        A.append(('x' + str(i), 'y' + str(i)))

    for i in range(10 ** n):
        B.append(('y' + str(i), 'z' + str(i)))

    start = time()
    joined = natural_join(A ,B)
    end = time()
    print('{:d}, {:E}'.format(10 ** n, (end-start)/n))
```